# Where does Content Provider store data?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Why `Content Provider` is not considered as Data storage option in android [Data Storage Options in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

and where do `content providers` store their data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are considered different to the other because they provide a way to globally share data between applications. The other data storage options are private to that application.

As for where they store their data:
From the docs:

"How a content provider actually stores its data under the covers is up to its designer."