# Content Provider: where is it exactly created and stored?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have created a  content provider for my app. I wanted to know where exactly is the location or path for the database that is created in content provider. Does uninstalling the app also delete the content providers? If I want to change the number of columns in the content provider how should I upgrade it?

Answer (score 1):

A content provider is not a database, but a component that offers some advantages, as the one of making content searchable from the main device.
The DB is not strictly dependent by the Content Provider. What the content provider does is to furnish an interface to the database, by mean of an Uri, and Authority.
So to reply to your question yes if you cancel your app, you are going also to cancel the DB, because cancelling the app, and even the content providers class will be cancelled

Answer (score 0):

Quick Search on SO:

> where exactly is the location or path for the database that is created in content provider

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279118/where-does-content-provider-store-data)

"How a content provider actually stores its data under the covers is up to its designer."

> Does uninstalling the app also delete the content providers?

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859318/if-my-app-created-a-android-content-provider-will-the-provider-disappear-if-my)

There are 2 ways of using/changing Content Provider

To make changes the default content provider, such as contacts. If your app added an entry of contact, the contact is still there even the app gets deleted

To make your own content provider. But this gets removed when the app gets uninstalled.

> If I want to change the number of columns in the content provider how should I upgrade it?

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455482/android-content-provider-update-certain-columns)

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(HabitTable.TIME); //whatever column you want to update, I dont know the name of it

...//any other values you want to update too

getContentResolver().update(HabitTable.CONTENT_URI,values,HabitTable.ID+"=?",new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}); //id is the id of the row you wan to update
```